# Adding column to PySpark DataFrame depending on whether column value is in another column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DataFrame with structure given by

```
[('u1', 1, [1 ,2, 3]), ('u1', 4, [1, 2, 3])].toDF('user', 'item', 'fav_items')
```

I need to add a further column with 1 or 0 depending on whether 'item' is in 'fav_items' or not.

So I would want

```
[('u1', 1, [1 ,2, 3], 1), ('u1', 4, [1, 2, 3], 0)]
```

How would I look up for second column into third column to decide value and how would I then add it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code does the requested task. An user defined function was defined that receives two columns of a `DataFrame` as parameters. So, for each row, search if an item is in the item list. If the item is found, a 1 is return, otherwise a 0.

```
# Imports
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
# First we create a RDD in order to create a dataFrame:
rdd = sc.parallelize([('u1', 1, [1 ,2, 3]), ('u1', 4, [1, 2, 3])])
df = rdd.toDF(['user', 'item', 'fav_items'])
# Print dataFrame
df.show()

# We make an user define function that receives two columns and do operation
function = udf(lambda item, items: 1 if item in items else 0, IntegerType())

df.select('user', 'item', 'fav_items', function(col('item'), col('fav_items')).alias('result')).show()
```

Here the results:

```
+----+----+---------+
|user|item|fav_items|
+----+----+---------+
|  u1|   1|[1, 2, 3]|
|  u1|   4|[1, 2, 3]|
+----+----+---------+

+----+----+---------+------+
|user|item|fav_items|result|
+----+----+---------+------+
|  u1|   1|[1, 2, 3]|     1|
|  u1|   4|[1, 2, 3]|     0|
+----+----+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun non-UDF solution:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, first, explode, max as max_

result = (
    # Here we take exploded rows and for each row check if there
    # is a match. We cast to integer (false -> 0, true -> 1)
    # and take max (1 if there is any match)
    max_((col("fav_item") == col("item")).cast("integer"))
).alias("result")


(df.repartition("user", "item") 
  # Explode array so we compare item and fav_item
  .withColumn("fav_item", explode("fav_items")) 
  .groupBy("user", "item")
  # Aggregate
  # we add result and retain fav_items
  .agg(result, first("fav_items").alias("fav_items")))
```

So it just:

- unrolls `fav_array`:

  ```
  ## +----+----+---------+--------+
  ## |user|item|fav_items|fav_item|
  ## +----+----+---------+--------+
  ## |  u1|   1|[1, 2, 3]|       1|
  ## |  u1|   1|[1, 2, 3]|       2|
  ## |  u1|   1|[1, 2, 3]|       3|
  ## |  u1|   4|[1, 2, 3]|       1|
  ## |  u1|   4|[1, 2, 3]|       2|
  ## |  u1|   4|[1, 2, 3]|       3|
  ## +----+----+---------+--------+
  ```
- checks if `fav_item` = `item` (`_1` is a result of `(col("fav_item") == col("item")).cast("integer")` expression):

  ```
  ## +----+----+---------+--------+---+
  ## |user|item|fav_items|fav_item| _1|
  ## +----+----+---------+--------+---+
  ## |  u1|   1|[1, 2, 3]|       1|  1|
  ## |  u1|   1|[1, 2, 3]|       2|  0|
  ## |  u1|   1|[1, 2, 3]|       3|  0|
  ## |  u1|   4|[1, 2, 3]|       1|  0|
  ## |  u1|   4|[1, 2, 3]|       2|  0|
  ## |  u1|   4|[1, 2, 3]|       3|  0|
  ## +----+----+---------+--------+---+
  ```
- and rolls it back keeping `user` and `item` as group columns, an arbitrary `fav_items` (all are the same) and maximum of temporary column `_1` (0 or 1).

I would go with UDF though.

Comment: Very clever but I don't understand it Mr. Zero, could you give a deeper explanation?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Sure, I've simplified the code and added some comments.