# PySpark - Dynamically update a col depending on the value of a cell

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is a modified version of the problem posted here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898687/adding-column-to-pyspark-dataframe-depending-on-whether-column-value-is-in-anoth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898687/adding-column-to-pyspark-dataframe-depending-on-whether-column-value-is-in-anoth%20here)

I am using Pyspark (spark 1.6)

I have the following data:

```
myDict
{'1': 'c1', '3': 'c3', '2': 'c2', '5': 'c5', '4': 'c4', '6': 'c6'}
```

I have the foll df:

```
+----+----+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|user|item|fav_items| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6|
+----+----+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  u1|   1|    1,1,3|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  u1|   4|4,4,4,5,6|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
+----+----+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The output should be:

```
+----+----+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|user|item|fav_items| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6|
+----+----+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  u1|   1|    1,1,3|  2|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|  u1|   4|4,4,4,5,6|  0|  0|  0|  3|  1|  1|
+----+----+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Depending on the cound and values in fav_items, lookup myDict to get the column mapping and update the column. For instance, for the first row we have 1 occuring twice, and 1 maps to 'c1' from myDict and therefore value for c1 for row 1 should be 2.

I got the following method working where we can iterate over columns but this approach is inefficient since the number of columns exceeds 2k+.

```
for key in myDict.keys():
    contains_event = udf(lambda x: x.count(key), IntegerType())
    df = df.withColumn(myDict[key], contains_event('fav_items'))
```

I'm looking for a more efficient method for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried in my way, hope it helps.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> from pyspark.sql imoport functions as F
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {'1': 'c1', '3': 'c3', '2': 'c2', '5': 'c5', '4': 'c4', '6': 'c6'}
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([('u1',1,'1,1,3',0,0,0,0,0,0),('u1',4,'4,4,4,5,6',0,0,0,0,0,0),('u1',1,'3,6,2',0,0,0,0,0,0)],['user','item','fav_items','c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6'])
>>> df.show()
+----+----+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|user|item|fav_items| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6|
+----+----+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  u1|   1|    1,1,3|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  u1|   4|4,4,4,5,6|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  u1|   1|    3,6,2|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
+----+----+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
>>> udf1 = F.udf(lambda c: Counter(c).most_common(),ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType())))
>>>  df1 = df.select('user','item','fav_items',udf1(F.split(df.fav_items,',')).alias('item_counter'))
>>> df1.show(3,False)
+----+----+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|user|item|fav_items|item_counter                                                |
+----+----+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|u1  |1   |1,1,3    |[WrappedArray(1, 2), WrappedArray(3, 1)]                    |
|u1  |4   |4,4,4,5,6|[WrappedArray(4, 3), WrappedArray(5, 1), WrappedArray(6, 1)]|
|u1  |1   |3,6,2    |[WrappedArray(3, 1), WrappedArray(6, 1), WrappedArray(2, 1)]|
+----+----+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+

>>> df2 = df2.select('user','item','fav_items','val',df2.val[0].alias('val1'),df2.val[1].alias('val2'))
>>> df2.show()
+----+----+---------+------+----+----+
|user|item|fav_items|   val|val1|val2|
+----+----+---------+------+----+----+
|  u1|   1|    1,1,3|[1, 2]|   1|   2|
|  u1|   1|    1,1,3|[3, 1]|   3|   1|
|  u1|   4|4,4,4,5,6|[4, 3]|   4|   3|
|  u1|   4|4,4,4,5,6|[5, 1]|   5|   1|
|  u1|   4|4,4,4,5,6|[6, 1]|   6|   1|
|  u1|   1|    3,6,2|[3, 1]|   3|   1|
|  u1|   1|    3,6,2|[6, 1]|   6|   1|
|  u1|   1|    3,6,2|[2, 1]|   2|   1|
+----+----+---------+------+----+----+

>>> udf2 = F.udf(lambda x : d[x],StringType())
>>> df2 = df2.withColumn('d_col',udf2(df2.val1))
>>> df2.show()
+----+----+---------+------+----+----+-----+
|user|item|fav_items|   val|val1|val2|d_col|
+----+----+---------+------+----+----+-----+
|  u1|   1|    1,1,3|[1, 2]|   1|   2|   c1|
|  u1|   1|    1,1,3|[3, 1]|   3|   1|   c3|
|  u1|   4|4,4,4,5,6|[4, 3]|   4|   3|   c4|
|  u1|   4|4,4,4,5,6|[5, 1]|   5|   1|   c5|
|  u1|   4|4,4,4,5,6|[6, 1]|   6|   1|   c6|
|  u1|   1|    3,6,2|[3, 1]|   3|   1|   c3|
|  u1|   1|    3,6,2|[6, 1]|   6|   1|   c6|
|  u1|   1|    3,6,2|[2, 1]|   2|   1|   c2|
+----+----+---------+------+----+----+-----+

>>> pvtdf = df2.groupby(['user','item','fav_items']).pivot('d_col').agg(F.first('val2')).na.fill({'c1':0,'c2':0,'c3':0,'c4':0,'c5':0,'c6':0})
>>> pvtdf.show()
+----+----+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|user|item|fav_items| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6|
+----+----+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  u1|   1|    1,1,3|  2|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|  u1|   1|    3,6,2|  0|  1|  1|  0|  0|  1|
|  u1|   4|4,4,4,5,6|  0|  0|  0|  3|  1|  1|
+----+----+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh.  Let me try this out.